# How to echo a wordpress php tag

Tags: wordpress

This will probably get answered quickly but I wanted to know how i can echo out a PHP wordpress template tag when I am already echoing HTML

`<?php echo wp_logout_url();?>` isn't working for me. it's adding the php code rather than the permalink to log out.

can anyone help?

Thanks.

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<li>Employee Portal</li>';
        echo '<li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="/employee-portal/">Employee Portal</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're doing double echo. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, because you are already in php with `<?php` and you are already echos.
Use this instead:

```
echo '<li><a href="' . wp_logout_url(); .'" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>';
```

or this

```
<?php
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        ?> <!-- step out from PHP code, from here is HTML -->
        <li>Employee Portal</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>
        <?php //<!-- go back to PHP
    } else {
        ?> <!-- step out from PHP code, from here is HTML -->
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="/employee-portal/">Employee Portal</a></li>
        <?php //<-- go back to PHP
    }
?>
```

Comment: can you link  me up with a guide on how to use the `dots` correctly in php? @lolka_bolka

Comment: thank you!! i had to tweak your code a bit it worked!

Comment: oh, yes, i see, some of my comment was bad outside of php. i edited. thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can just concatenate the function in the string using "**.**"

```
echo '<li><a href="' . wp_logout_url(). '" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>';
```

or use [printf](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.printf.php)

```
printf( '<li><a href="%s" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>', wp_logout_url() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this:

```
echo '<li><a href="' .wp_logout_url();.'" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: For the official documentation check out [PHP string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)